# Is it possible to add an IF condition to create a comment if a condition is met?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a sheet connected to a form and my users sometimes add cases many times which causes duplicates, I solved this by adding conditional coloring to the duplicated sheets.

Now I want to know if it's possible to add an IF rule in a case that duplicates found in the red color (which represents a duplicate) to add a comment automatically?

Comment: Welcome. Do you mean that you are looking to add the condition to the conditional formatting rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(A2:A, A2:A)>1, "Duplicate", ))
```

[image: 0]